# the variance of a gaussian PDF?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, density-function

A problem is this: 
The probability density function of the univariate Gaussian with mean $ μ $ and variance $σ2,  N(μ,σ2)$:

$$f_x(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt(2*pi*σ2)} * e^-(x-μ)^2/(2*σ2)$$

The pdf of a Gaussian random variable X is given by:
$$ f_x(x) = \frac{n}{(3*\sqrt(2*pi))} * exp(-(n^2(x-2)^2)/18)$$.

What is the mean and variance of X?

I got the mean right: 2, but the variance wrong:9.

Why is 9 not the right answer here? I thought it would be $3^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omit $n$ in the expression. Your PDF can be written as
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(3/n)}\exp(-(x-2)^2/(2(3/n)^2))$$
where $\sigma_2=3/n$.

Comment: I see, thanks Gunes!